# Update local subversion web based

Tags: svn, repository

I would like to access a web-page and see all my project files like this:

```
\path
 \file1 local version: 4711 latest version in svn 5110 (update with a link)
 \file2 local version: 4711 latest version in svn 4711
..
```

Right now, I do a `svn up` which updates all my files or all file within a directory. But i don't always want to update all files and I don't want to `svn up file1 file2`

Edit: I use debian on the servers w/o any window managers

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Install some GUI over SVN For example, with TortoiseSVN, you can

- right-click on a folder
- Choose "Check for modifications"
- Click "Check repository"
- select the added/deleted/modified files you want to update
- right-click
- choose "update"

Comment: Yeah, great idea.. I just forgot to say I use debian and I have no window manager installed.. Sorry, I updated my question

Comment: How would a web page be useful then? Would you browse it using lynx? TortoiseSVN is a client tool. It doesn't run on the server, but on the client.

Comment: The webpage could access the local filesystem of the server and execute any svn commands. I could access the webpage with my default browser via internet. Sorry for any confusions!

Comment: I repeat: TortoiseSVN is a client tool. It doesn't have to be installed on the server. It's run from your client machine and accesses the server using the same protocol as the command-line SVN client. You don't need any access to the file system of the server to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use SVN Monitor - http://code.google.com/p/gs-lost-cause/
This is not a webtool, but on my oppinion this may be helpful for you